# How exactly does Health Level work?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

In *Final Fantasy XV*, there is an ascension trait called **Health Level**. It reads as follows:

> Increase HP of each party member by twice the number of levels gained. The effects of similar abilities do not stack.

Does this mean that if I unlocked this at, say, level 10, it would give my team 20HP? Is it a one-time thing, as soon as it's unlocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, your party members would gain 20HP. This is NOT a one time effect to my knowledge - they will continue to benefit from it as they level up.

The "effect of similar abilities" text is to signify that later Health Level bonuses **replace the earlier ones**, rather than stack.